# Звони́т, но трезво́нит. Почему?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Всем известно, что правильно говорить ***звони́т, перезвони́т, дозвони́ться.***
Однако же ни для кого не секрет, что очень многие путают тут ударение, ставя его на "о", видимо, по аналогии со словом "звон", а также с украинским "дзво́нить".
При этом, однако, есть вполне русское слово **трезво́нить**, которое происходит от слова **трезво́н** (разновидность церковного звона).

Почему же такая путаница в ударениях?

Answer (score 2):

Никакое украинское "дзвонит" и русское "звон" тут ни при чём. Просто в русском языке давно уже начался (и уже произошел для многих слов) процесс переноса ударения на корень у глаголов на -ит. Например: платИть но плАтит, рубИть но рУбит, и так далее (раньше было платИт, рубИт). То же самое по логике языка должно было бы произойти и со словом "звонит" (оно и произошло у большинства людей в разговорной речи). Но видимо на момент составления словарей  этот переход еще не произошёл. Затем граммар-наци уцепились за это слово - выбрали его как признак образованности (своей конечно прежде всего).

Ну а в "трезвонит", видимо, этот переход ударения на корень уже произошел на момент занесения его в словари.

Answer (score 0):

Ну давно известно, что ударение в русских словах не следует ни за этимологией, ни за морфологией. Родственные слова вполне могут иметь разные ударения.
Конкретно в нашем случае, видимо, произошло переразложение слова трезвон связь со звоном потерялась. Т.е. если бы "трезвонить" напрямую шло от "тре-" и "звонить" можно было ожидать общего места ударения со смешением на глагольный суффикс. Но поскольку "трезвон" воспринимается как обычное двусложное слово, то неподвижное ударение на корне более  ожидаемо. Сравните: филОн - филОнить, сифОн-сифОнить. 
Напротив, пары типа "завОд-заводИть", "поднОс-подносИть" и проч. не потеряли историческую морфологию - и потому в них смешение на суффикс понятно.

Answer (score 0):

**Звонит** (позвонит), **Звонят** (позвонят) должны и будут звучать по логике **Звоню** (позвоню), где на О ударять никто не станет ввиду неблагозвучности. Своего рода это — проверочное слово.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

Comment: Ваши версии есть?

Comment: Если Вы хотите дополнить ответ, пользуйтесь правкой, а не комментариями.

Comment: Ваш ответ править нет нужды. Оценит автор вопроса.